# No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 while doing sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I'm doing my 1st SQLite program on Android. This program allows the user to enter the details of a student and store it in the database. On invocation of `view_data()` an exception occurs.

Here is an image of the activity:

[image]

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    String str1,str2,str3;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    StringBuffer sb;
    AlertDialog.Builder ad;
    Cursor resultSet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("student_db", MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(s_id VARCHAR,s_name VARCHAR,s_batch VARCHAR);");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void insert_data(View view){
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        str1=et1.getText().toString();
        str2=et2.getText().toString();
        str3=et3.getText().toString();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO student VALUES('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "');");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"INSERTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void view_data(View view) {
        try {
            resultSet = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student;", null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),resultSet.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ad  = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            if(resultSet.getCount()==0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no records", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            while (resultSet.moveToNext()) {
                sb.append("Student ID-->"+resultSet.getString(0)+"\n");
                sb.append("Student Name-->"+resultSet.getString(1)+"\n");
                sb.append("Student Batch-->"+resultSet.getString(2)+"\n\n");
            }
            ad.setTitle("Student List");
            ad.setMessage(sb.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Student ID" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Student Name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sbatch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Student Batch" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Insert"
            android:onClick="insert_data"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="view_data"
            android:text="VIew"
            android:id="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
03-26 18:18:43.799 27324-27324/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15338: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15342: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-26 18:18:43.929 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 440: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-26 18:18:43.989 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 381: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 383: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-26 18:18:44.029 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.04.048.076_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: Build Date: 08/25/14 Mon
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: Local Branch: 
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.2
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: Local Patches: NONE
03-26 18:18:44.109 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/Adreno-EGL: Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.04.048.076 +  NOTHING
03-26 18:18:44.159 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-26 18:18:44.259 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e101b8 time:236109512
03-26 18:18:50.159 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e101b8 time:236115418
03-26 18:18:51.179 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
03-26 18:18:51.179 27324-27324/com.example.roopanrajesh.stud_db D/Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultSet.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Second parameter of `Toast.makeText` expects a `String` or a `@StringRes int`. Your result is an integer therefore it's treated as a string resource ID.

If you want to show the number, you need to convert it to String first:

```
"" + resultSet.getCount()
```

The same applies when you use `textView.setText(...)`.

#### Bonus

`Log.e("tag", e.toString())` doesn't print stack trace.

`Log.e("tag", "message", e)` does. You need to pass the exception as last parameter.

What you posted is not a stack trace.

Comment: oh sorry for the stack trace....anyway thanks for the help it worked...